# Two layers of underlayment for sheet vinyl?

Tags: vinyl-flooring, underlayment

I'm installing sheet vinyl flooring in the bathroom.  Home Depot told me to get this hard plywood, just under 1/4" thick for underlayment.  I'm concerned though because my sub floor is 10" or 12" wide boards with a good amount of gaps between them.  I was thinking of throwing another sheet of 3/8" OSB on top of the subfloor, then the 1/4" underlayment.  Is that a good idea, or bad idea?  Really needed?  I'm wondering if there will be a problem with the nails going through multiple layers of plywood?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal is a smooth, flat surface for the vinyl to lay on.  If you can do that with 1/4, then that is great.  But in your case it sounds like you need to step up to 3/8 or 1/2 depending on the gap.  Once you put that down, then there is no need to add 1/4 plywood.